# Export PostgreSQL using phppgadmin

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

I want to export and download my database using phppgadmin, but it always downloaded with 0 bytes.

what I do wrong?
Choose DBname > SQL > Then I choose structure and data> with format SQL> Then I choose Download for the option then click export

Comment: please refer http://www.expertphp.in/article/postgres-phppgadmin-problem-empty-sql-dump-after-export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because your postgres have different version between your db and phppgadmin